# Black lines appaear on edges of mesh when turning on smooth shading

Tags: shaders, edges, subdivision-surface

Kindly need help as I'm getting random specks or lines of black on the edges of my mesh. This only shows up when selecting "smooth" shading. Also I have subsurf modifier enabled. More over, adding more edge loops appears to trigger more of these weird black shading/lines. [image]

At this point I'm not sure if this is a bug or something which can be fixed. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add an image that shows the actual vertices of the object. It looks to me that you have overlapping geometry.

Comment: Yes, it appears you're right. It looks to be overlapping geometry as I developed a bad habit of adding & pushing my edge loops at the exact edges of the mesh. Fixed it already by using remove doubles and making sure my edge loops are not at the exact edges. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Please write an answer to your own question in the answers section. It might help other users who run into a similar situation. Make sure you include images of the problem and the way to fix it.